# Make a RibbonCombobox editable

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

In a WPF .Net 4.5 application, I'd like to have several editable combobox in the Ribbon, so I can either select a value in a list or type a custom value.

Using a regular `ComboBox` with `IsEditable="True"` and `IsReadOnly="False"` works well, but setting those two properties on a `RibbonComboBox` does not work : after typing the value, when I click outside the control or hit Enter, the typed value is replaced by the previous selected value from the list. The SelectionChanged event of the RibbonGallery is not triggered. 
(Selection from the drop-down list does work well and updates correctly the binded property.)

Here are some related posts :

[Editable riboncombobox problems with selected item](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57ac8e22-5ae6-4c06-9d3d-7407605e8248/editable-ribboncombobox-problems-with-selected-item?forum=wpf) same problem with no answer
[RibbonComboBox selected gallery item reverts to old value on mouse leave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998655/ribboncombobox-selected-gallery-item-reverts-to-old-value-on-mouse-leave) I tried the workaround in the 2d answer, to no avail. The problem also appears even when the mouse does not move so it's perhaps not related.

[Editable ribbon combo box does not respect choices that are not in the drop-down list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb9fec4e-4bab-4386-93e0-0d63eac60cea/editable-ribbon-combo-box-does-not-respect-choices-that-are-not-in-the-dropdown-list?forum=wpf) same problem but the solution requires to create a custom class to override the normal behaviour of RibbonComboBox. I haven't yet tested it but it seems anormal to me to have to do that to obtain what I consider a standard behaviour.

Here is the code for one of the troublesome ribboncomboboxes (Libelle is a string property that raise a PropertyChanged event when modified) :

```
<RibbonComboBox IsEditable="True"
                IsReadOnly="False"
                IsTextSearchEnabled="False">
<RibbonGallery IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
               SelectedValue="{Binding Libelle}" >
    <RibbonGalleryCategory IsTextSearchEnabled="False">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="sys:String">
                <sys:String>Zero hydro</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Cote marine</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Mouillage</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Profondeur</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Hauteur d'eau</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
        </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsSource>
    </RibbonGalleryCategory>
</RibbonGallery>
```

I'm not very familiar with the RibbonComboBox element so I'm wondering whether I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you miss ...
This bug .. and have to write it ..

```
    private void RibbonGallery_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
```